# Custom splash screen

Tags: osx, template

I want to create a custom splash screen in Blender 3.1.

I have created an application template in the Blender.app contents, where all the other templates go. I can access the template in Blender, but what I would like to do is make it load by default.

Is this even possible on a Mac?

Comment: The question referenced in the "duplicate" question is for blender 2.67, all the links are dead, and the suggestions don't work. I am using blender 3.0 and 3.1 on a PC, and there is no "splash.png" in my datafiles folder, or anywhere in the blender folder for that matter (even with hidden files enabled). Please re-open so we can get an answer. Suggestions are unclear if building a custom version of blender from scratch is necessary, or how to do it with newer versions.

Answer (score 6):

There is no official support for changing a splash screen, although there is a [feature request](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/K8wr/?sorting=hot) on Right-CLick Select.

You can't simply replace the splash screen but you can create an [Application Template](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/app_templates.html) that has a custom splash screen.  These steps are taken from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0EbNai8dYq4&t=13s) on YouTube:

- Create a new folder in PATH_TO_BLENDER_INSTALLATION/version/scripts/startup/bl_app_template_system
- copy your startup files from your startup area (on Windows AppData/Roaming/Blender Foundation/Blender/VERSION/config; someone else will have to verify OSX) to the folder you just created.
- add the two png files that you want for your splash screen (splash.png and splash_2x.png) to the template folder you created in the first step.
- setup a shortcut (windows) or alias (your favorite shell) to start blender using the application template you just created.  The command is `blender --log --app-template TEMPLATE_NAME`

Anytime you use the shortcut (or alias) you'll have a setup with your new splash screen.

NOTE: "splash.png" must be spelled that way and must be a 1000x500 png file.

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett  You're welcome.  Thanks for getting the question reopened.